# How to get the texture segment that I have selected on an ico sphere

Tags: export

I am trying to split a planet texture into chunks and then put them onto a sphere in my game. However, I'm very new to blender and I'm not really sure how. I have UV unwrapped an Ico Sphere, and added a texture to it, but I don't know how to export the small bit of texture that I have selected, and how to export it as a whole image, not split up. Here is a screenshot of where I'm at:

[image: planet UV thing]

(The game engine I'm using only allows meshes with up to 10k triangles, if anyone is wondering why I even want to do this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So If I understand, all you need to do is just to separate bits of your sphere into different objects ti fit them into your game engine, you don't need to separate the corresponding bits of textures.

All you have to do is to select the part you want to separate like you did, then press <kbd>P</kbd> > *Separate By Selection*. It will separate the selected mesh into a new object. Repeat for each part you want.

Then you can export each object as is, they should have the same material using the same texture.
When importing in your game engine, make sure each imported piece uses the same material.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for the help, I really appreicate it!